# Why is my camera very narrow?

Tags: rendering, camera

I was making GFX for a friend of mine and I was about to render the image using the camera but instead of being normal it was very narrow, almost just a line, which made it impossible to capture the graphic. I have seen other people doing this but their camera is completely normal. Here is a screenshot. [image: Screenshot Proof -- Camera in middle] Why does this happen? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

In the *Properties* panel > *Render*, Your Render *Resolution* is 10 000 x 1 080 and the *Aspect Ratio* is 200 x 1...